# How to access a module from outside your file folder in Python?

Tags: python

How can I access modules from another folder?

Here's the file structure:

```
/<appname>
    /config
        __init__.py
        config.py
    /test
        test.py # I'm here
```

I wanted to access the functions from config.py from test.py . How would I do this?
Here is my import:

```
import config.config
```

When I run the `test.py` script, it will always say:

```
ImportError: No module named config.config
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You can use `os.path` shenanigans to move around your relative path. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path?rq=1

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The simplest way is to modify the `sys.path` variable (it defines the import search path):

```
# Bring your packages onto the path
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'config')))

# Now do your import
from config.config import *
```

Comment: what is ".." in here, please explain

Comment: It's standard path semantics for "up one directory" when dealing with a relative path.

Comment: if you want to up 2 directory, just replace '..' to '../..'

Comment: Well, not quite. This is inside a `join` block. So you'd do `join('..','..','config')`

Comment: Instead of `'..'` one can use `os.path.pardir` . So it becomes: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.pardir, 'config')))`

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar but way more confusing than this:
`import sys`
`parent_folder = "\\".join(sys.path[0].split("\\")[:-1])`
`sys.path.append(parent_folder)`
`import config`

Answer (score 20):

Yo can only import modules that are visible by your environment. You can check the environment using this.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

As you will see sys.path is a list so you can append elements to it:

```
sys.path.append('/path_to_app/config')
```

And you should be able to import your module.

BTW: There is plenty of questions about this.

Answer (score 12):

Add the app directory to the module search path.

For example:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/appname python test.py
```

Comment: you're a legend!

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Mohith7548, prepend `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/appname` before the command. (assuming unix, the module is in `/path/to/appname` directory)

Comment: Okay, that's informative. How about in windows?

Comment: @Mohith7548 Execute `set PYTHONPATH=...`, then the command.