# Cannot find module when importing from project in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My directory structure looks like this:

[image: directory_structure]

I have some utility functions in `util/misc.py` that I want to import in `compose_dataset.py`. However, I cannot get the import statement to work.

I'm working on Windows Python3.5.4, so from what I've read I don't need `__init__.py` files anymore. The project folder is a child of my `PYTHONPATH` that points solely to E:\Python. So far, I tried:

```
from misc import *
from util import *
from util.misc import *
from ..util.misc import *
```

and either received `ImportError: No module named 'xyz'` or `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I also tried adding init-files but I have no experience with those and simply added one to every directory, but (surprisingly) that didn't work either.

What am I missing here??

Comment: You need the `src` folder to be on your `PYTHONPATH` in in your working directory, otherwise `from src.util.misc import *` should work.

Comment: Did you try the `__init__.py` in the `util` folder anyways ?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is now "E:\Python, "E:\Python\Project\src"" and I still get `No module named 'src'`. Also, is adding every single project folder's src folder to the path variable really a good long-term solution?

Comment: @bhnn if you add `src` to `PYTHONPATH` you then don't need to include it in the import: `from util.misc import *`

Comment: @PeterWood I tried that but it didn't work. If I just add `src` to `PYTHONPATH`, my `sys.path` variable later contains `/src` and `/src/data` during runtime, but not `/src/util`. That has been causing the problems. If I add it manually like I commented below, it works fine, but the linter still shows an error because the correction obviously only happens at runtime. Do you know what would cause this weird behaviour?

Comment: `sys.path` shouldn't contain `/src/util` it should contain `/src` then you say `from util import misc` or similar.

Comment: But when `sys.path` only contains `/src` the import statement does not work, only when `/src/util` is added manually to the path. What you're saying is what most sources state as the correct way, so there has to be something wrong with the `sys.path` that makes it malfunction right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
from util.misc import *
```

You may also want to take a look at this post: [How to access a module from outside your file folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868733/how-to-access-a-module-from-outside-your-file-folder-in-python)

Comment: `PYTHONPATH`now contains the `'../',` path, but the import statement still does not recognise `util`

Comment: Did you add `__init__.py` to your sub folders? This way Python treats your folders as modules. An empty `__init__.py` would do.

Comment: Yep, there's an init file in the root directory and every sub-directory right now. Still the same ImportError.

Comment: Could you try `sys.path.append` instead of `insert` just like the link I provided up there in my answer?

Comment: Hm, looks like for some reason `/src` and `/src/data` were automatically included into the `PYTHONPATH` just from putting the absolute path to `/src` into it. It was missing a link to `/src/util` though. Using `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('./src', 'util')))` fixed it. Weird though, that it would automatically recognise the other subfolder but not this one...

Answer (score 0):

Set your `PYTHONPATH` to `.`, and add `__init__.py` files into each directory, where you want to import from, in your case add it into `src`, `data`, `util` directories. Assuming that you run your "entry point" script from the root directory of your project (same where your `README.md` file is), to import use this code:

```
# compose_dataset.py file
from src.util.misc import function_name
```