# Import a custom module in the parent folder in python

Tags: python

Although I think this should be pretty simple I still can't make it run.

I have following folder structure:

```
├── apartment          
│   ├── src        
│       ├── train_model
│           ├── __init__.py 
│           ├── train_model.py
│           ├── utils.py
│       ├── interference.py
│       └── __init__.py
```

In `utils.py` I tried:

```
from src.interference import create_sample
```

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

```
from .interference import create_sample
```

> Error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
from interference import create_features_sample
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interference'

What is the way to make it work? I am not a huge fan of non-pythonic ways as it looks dirty.

Comment: OP, don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it helped you, to help others

Comment: What command are you using to run your script? Is it `python utils.py` or something else? Please edit the question and add it ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure starting with a `src/` is aimed explicitly at *not* enabling import by `from src.intereference import ...`, and you should not put an `__init__.py` file in `src/` folder.

Instead, following nice explanation and examples here: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/, here is what I recommend:

- install the package:

  - add a `setup.py` file at root of your folder (this is clearly not as hard as it seems)
  - maybe create a virtual environment
  - using `pip install -e .` (with trailing dot!) command
- then simply import your package by `from interference import ...`

To answer to your primary request, you could update `src/__init__.py` with `from intereference import create_sample`, to expose this function at a higher level, then the chained import would work. However, I do not recommend this, as it renders everything very rigid.

Comment: Isn't already a __init__ there? The one below interference.py

Comment: There is indeed, but the structure is kinda weird, hence my proposal for improvement. However, I may have not understood the structure correctly so I may update my answer.

Comment: I think we just need to answer how to import interference from utils

Comment: @Joël After your comment about the weird structure I realized that it is indeed weird, so I changed it . Thank you!

Comment: @Anni glad I could help! If you found a nice way to structure your project, then you may create a new answer and explain there how it now looks like :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directory that contains interference to `PYTHONPATH`.

You can use OS depending path in "module search path" which is listed in `sys.path`. So you can easily add parent directory like following:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')

from interference import create_features_sample
```

Note that the previous code uses a relative path, so you must launch the file inside the same location or it will likely not work.
To launch from anywhere, you can use `Path` from the `pathlib` module.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import sys
path = str(Path(Path(__file__).parent.absolute()).parent.absolute())
sys.path.insert(0, path)

from interference import create_features_sample
```

Comment: This would only add the the module temporarily.

Comment: Which is what they want in most cases. You don't want to pollute your PYTHONPATH with every single random projects + it will be executed when the file is launched, so I don't really see your point here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `from ..interference import create_sample` ?

Or for the whole module `from .. import interference`.

I've checked here, that I'm using another command, something that is missing from the question at the time of writing this. The command that I'm using is `python -m src.train_model.utils` from `apartment` folder.

Thanks to [RMPR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8873120/rmpr) for helping me.

This problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11536764/7395911).

Comment: ```  File "utils.py", line 2
    import ..interferences
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: It's interference not interferences

Comment: I named it interferences for my tests

Comment: @RMPR It should be `from .. import interference`

Comment: for the second one I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` .. you need to add the folder to PYTHONPATH

Comment: @RMPR I was using another command, as not explicitly stated in the question we came to a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add a custom path to your PYTHONPATH permanently, go to the 'site-packages' folder of your current Python environment and add the file 'custompaths.pth' in which each line should consist of a directory which will then be checked if you try to import the module.

Assuming 'src' being the module you want to import you should add the following line to the .pth file:

*your_preceding_path/apartment*

Answer (score 0):

Error because of python can't able to find the specific file or package. Python usually find only for the child packages or files, otherwise you need to specify the absolute path.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('../..', 'src')))
```

Please refer the "[How to access a module from outside your file folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868733/how-to-access-a-module-from-outside-your-file-folder-in-python)"