# Getting python file outside of folder

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm try to import my main python file but it's not working.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from ..bot import bot
class help(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    @commands.command(name="help", aliases=["Help"])
    async def help(self,context, message = None):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help command")
        cmds = ""
        if message == None:
            bot.listcom(cmds)
            embed.add_field(name="Commands", value=cmds)
        if not message == None:
            pass
        await context.send(embed=embed)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(help(client))
```

Terminal Output:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I tried using import ..bot but it gave a syntax error and when I tried using just import bot it said it didn't exist. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Relative imports only work for submodules inside packages. It might be helpful if you show your folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868877/16237426
found that..

in your case that should work:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..')))
from bot import bot
```