# Why can't Python import a file from a relative path?

Tags: python, django, file, import

I found [this question helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868733/how-to-access-a-module-from-outside-your-file-folder-in-python), but Python is unable still to find the folder.

I have a Django folder structure that looks like this:

- todoproject

  - pythonDiscordChatbot

    - processLessons.py
  - todoapp

    - testChatFunctions.py

I'm trying to import a function called 'routes' into testChatFunctions.py, but I keep getting this error:

```
 File "c:\Users\Kaij\Documents\chatSiteDjango\todoproject\todoapp\testChatFunctions.py", line 6, in <module>tSiteDjango\todoproject\todoapp\tesssLesson import *tChatFunctions.py", line 6, in <modd 'pythonDiscordChatbot'ule>                               atSiteDjango> & C:/Users/Kaij/Documents/djangoTests/django_tailwind_project/env/Scripts/
    from pythonDiscordChatbot.procechatSiteDjango/todoproject/todoapp/testChatFunctions.pyssLesson import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module nametSiteDjango\todoproject\todoapp\testChatFunctions.py", line 6, in <module>d 'pythonDiscordChatbot
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
# Bring your packages onto the path
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'pythonDiscordChatbot')))

# Now do your import
from pythonDiscordChatbot.processLesson import *

# from pythonDiscordChatbot.processLesson import routes
routes("hello", "website_180.02.1")
```

Comment: have you tried adding `__init__.py` file in the `pythonDiscordChatbot` folder?

Comment: I really don't think you should need to add an __init__.py file. Also, is the error actually coming out exactly like that? Because it seems odd to have what looks like 2 separate strings randomly jumbled together like that.