# Can I install wget on my d drive instead of c drive using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence

My python is installed on my c drive. However, I'd like wget to be installed on my d drive instead so that I can import wget from my environment I created in my d drive. I used jupyter notebook to run the code. Any solution? [image: No module named 'wget']

Comment: You need to make sure you've got the install location on your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to install package to another directory using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip) for installing the package to another directory by using —target

And
[Accessing modules from outside env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868733/how-to-access-a-module-from-outside-your-file-folder-in-python) to access it by modifying sys.path